# Unity2D Enemy AI chasing player until pushing player through walls

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-development

I have  a 2D platformer in Unity, the enemy has AI scripts that make it patrol and chase depending on if the player is within trigger range. The player and enemy both have colliders and rigidbodies. Both of which are continuous.

This is the player RB
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KE036.png)

This is the enemy RB
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bFlfU.png)

and this is how the enemy moves
`Vector2 newPos = Vector2.MoveTowards(obj.transform.position, playerObj.position, chaseSpeed * Time.deltaTime); enemyRb.MovePosition(newPos);`

Here's my test
[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bpAen.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dhfGm.png)

This is the closest I can get and the enemy moves towards the player fine and even gets slower as hes right there. but once the player gets pushed to the corner he goes through and gets in there until the enemy pushes him out. He should stay on the platform. I'm not sure what other things I can try besides the project settings physics tab which I set the mefault max depenetration velocity to like 99999 and it still didn't work